# Multiple conditions inside C# Initializer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a way to handle multiple conditions inside C# Object initializer.

For example, to handle ColValue == "A", set "Value A" for everything else, set "Value X", we could use

```
new ObjectType
{
  Value =  string.Equals(ColValue, "A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)? "Value A" : "Value X"
};
```

How can we achieve, If ColValue == "A", set "Value A", If ColValue == "B", set "Value B" else set "Value X"

Comment: `A ? A : B ? B : C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more ternary operators inside to handle more conditions. like this:

```
new ObjectType
{
    Value = ColValue == "A" ? "Value A" : (ColValue == "B" ? "Value B" : "Value X")
};
```